# Hair mesh not moving with rig

Tags: animation, texturing, rigging

I'm trying to rig and animate a Hulk object I found off the internet. But, when I try posing the armature, the hair texture doesn't move with the rig. I'm brand new to Blender so please walk me through a solution step by step.

Here's a picture of the problem:
[image: Hair texture not moving with object]

I've uploaded my blender file and assets [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_k1-97vYIsifmFaYl9nMWhydWJUYjBDOHI3TUFaSEphUkdDRmk0aW51eHM2R2VBWGpvNkU&usp=sharing). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to Weight Paint mode and paint over the hair, or even better all over the head. While Bone.004(which is the head bone) is selected.

[image]